# how to use tastypie reverse relation

Tags: django, reverse, tastypie

When I do something like this http://example.com/api/v1/nisit/?format=json. I will get this error "The model '' has an empty attribute 'page' and doesn't allow a null value."

I want to use reverse relation of tastypie. reverse to the "page" model form "nisit" model. the result that i want is to call 127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/nisit/?format=json&friend_*followingPage*_id=1

The point of problem is "how can to set followingPage attribute in Nisit model  is the reverse relation to the followingNisit attribute in Page model

this is my model

```
 class Nisit(models.Model):
       friends =  models.ManyToManyField('self',null=True,blank=True)


 class Page(models.Model):
       followingNisit = models.ManyToManyField(Nisit,blank=True)
```

this is my resource

```
class NisitResource(ModelResource):
     friend = fields.ManyToManyField('self','friend',null=True)
     followingPage = fields.ToManyField('chula.api.resourse.PageResource','followingPage')
     class Meta:
        queryset = Nisit.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'nisit'
        filtering = {
            'friend' : ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
            'id' : ALL,
        }
```

In above code. I try to code >>>> page=................. according to this link http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#reverse-relationships
but it can't help

```
class PageResource(ModelResource):
    followingNisit = fields.ManyToManyField(NisitResource, 'followingNisit',null=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Page.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'page'
        authorization= Authorization()
        filtering = {
            'followingNisit': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
            'p_name': ALL,
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
class Page(models.Model):
     followingNisit = models.ManyToManyField(Nisit,blank=True, related_name="followingPage")
```

Clear your cache and maybe remove all your `null=True` might suppress that error message.